# Migrate data from one version of WSO2 Governance Registry to another one

Tags: wso2

We use WSO2 Registry Governance 4.5.3 and ask ourselves how to get information introduced (Resources, Users, LifeCycle ...) from one version to another. I saw that check-in can help.

Is it able to work with different versions of WSO2 Greg and will it take information other than resources, it seems that not.

But then how to transfer automatically these other infos from one version to another ? Is it possible through an API and which ?

Thank you in advance for your response.
Jean-Pierre Indot

Answer (score 0):

I tried migrating a datasource configuration (a basic text resource) from WSO2 GReg 4.1.1 to GReg 4.5.3 using the check-in client. The migration was successful.

But there is a possibility of this approach not being adequate for migrating more complex resources. (E.g.: Resources containing data structures)

Could you please share the nature of the resources you're trying to migrate, so that we can try to provide you with a more subjective solution.